# Audio crackle issues occur after some ui interactions

Tags: avaudioplayer, audiokit

Periodically have issues with crackling audio playback after ui interactions. I have so far been unable to reproduce the issues by repeating the same steps once the app is restarted. it seems to happen randomly. I'm looking for any insight into how i might track down the cause of this issue? or if anyone has had similar experiences and what to look out for?

[Example 1](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1d7IEvJ5LCqMqjrMAIvMy2r5RB6xcmw-p/view?usp=share_link)
[Example 2](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IVz76kB_ytVSEe8axX3VEf73uxUWy_N9/view?usp=share_link)

I have checked my audiokit configuration, and all seems about right. increasing the buffer length seems to have had no effect on this issue.

Here some of what i think could be most relevant parts of code

```
class PlaybackController : NSObject, AVAudioPlayerDelegate, ObservableObject
{
func loadContentsOfFiles (_ fileURLs: [URL])
    {
        print("call loader" )
        print(fileURLs.count)
        limiter.preGain = 10
        limiter.attackTime = 0.02
        playbackChannels.forEach{ $0.getAudioPlayer().stop() }
        playbackChannels.removeAll()
        fileURLs.forEach{addPlayer(withFileURL:$0)}
    }
    func loadContentsOfFiles (_ trackDatas: [MultiTrackData])
    {
        playbackChannels.forEach{ $0.getAudioPlayer().stop() }
        playbackChannels.removeAll()
        trackDatas.forEach{
            let fileManager = FileManager.default
            if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: $0.fileURL!.path)
            {
                print(" File is ready at \($0.fileURL)")
                addPlayer(withTrackData:$0)
            }
            else {
                print("File does not exist at \($0.fileURL)")
            }
        }
    }
    private func addPlayer(withFileURL url: URL) {
        playbackChannels.append(PlaybackChannel(name: "Loop", audioFile: url, mixer: mainMixer))
    }
}

//Playback channel
class PlaybackChannel: ObservableObject, Hashable {
    init(name: String, audioFile: URL, mixer: Mixer, audioPlayer: AudioPlayer = AudioPlayer()) {
        self.name = name
        self.audioFile = audioFile
        self.audioPlayer = audioPlayer
        self.volume = 1.0
        self.timePitch = TimePitch(audioPlayer)
        addPlayer(withFileURL: audioFile, mixer)
    }
    
    private func addPlayer(withFileURL url: URL, _ mixer: Mixer) {
        guard let player = AudioPlayer(url: url, buffered: true) else { fatalError("Could not create player") }
        let timePitch = TimePitch(player)
        mixer.addInput(timePitch)
        self.audioPlayer = player
        self.timePitch = timePitch
    }
}
```

the playbackController is initialized at the beginiing and is accessed as a shared object across the entire app. "PlaybackController.shared.loadContentsOfFiles" for example

Comment: Does the crackle only occur in a specific device? Did you try others? Mac, iphone, ipad, simulator?

Comment: how did you fix it? I have the same issue

Comment: @NatSerrano My issue was related to cpu usage. I had an issue where previous audio players were not removed correctly causing cpu and memory spikes which were exaggerated when ui interactions were triggered. Run your app while looking at the profiler to see if you have the same issue.